# Pass ag-grid data from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

New to react from angular 
Receiving the error:

```
The above error occurred in the <div> component: in div
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

I don't quite understand why div and what the error is talking about?
I am trying to click on a row and pass the values from row to parent. 
In my top level parent component, I have a function that would set the value of the selected row and in the child, the selected row is pass to props.

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      activeItem: []
    }

    this.setActiveItem = this.setActiveItem.bind(this)
  }

  setActiveItem = userSelect => {
    this.setState({ activeItem: userSelect })
  }

render(){
     <Child activeItem={this.setActiveItem}/>
}
```

In my child, I use ag-grid using `onRowClicked`. The error is getting thrown in `this.props.setActiveItem(event.data)`

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
     }
    onRowClicked = event => {
        //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('tester', event.data) //okay, shows data
        this.props.setActiveItem(event.data) //not okay, throws error
      }

    grid = () => {
        return (
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            rowData={this.state.data}
            onRowClicked={this.onRowClicked}
          />
        )
      }
    render() {
        if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
          return <div className="ag-mod">{this.grid()}</div>
        }
        return <br />
      }
}
    //also here's the prop for child
    Child.propTypes = {
      setActiveItem: PropTypes.func
    }
```

Comment: Still looking at your code, But I notice you are binding the method setActiveItem in the parent. Since this method is created using the es6 arrow function,  you didn't need to execute this.setActiveItem = this.setActiveItem.bind(this) in parents constructor. Try removing that.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing down setActiveItem from parent to child as activeItem.

```
<Child activeItem={this.setActiveItem}/>
```

So in child call it with the name you gave in when passing it down.

```
onRowClicked = event => {
    //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('tester', event.data) //okay, shows data
    this.props.activeItem(event.data) //not okay, throws error
  }
```

Also, consider wrapping your components in an error boundary as the error mentioned. It helps. You can read about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)